# How to write query to get exact details of user taking leave by summing their leave taken days as per their user id

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I am building a Laravel project for the Attendance Management System. In there I want to show the user leave details in their dashboard.

**Leave Table**

[Leave Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY7tX.jpg)

**Leave Application Table**
[Leave Application Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJN2F.jpg)

Actually, I want to show all the different type of leave that's the user take, their sum of leave taken days by the user and total leave days.

**Dashboard Controller**

**Getting the leave id**

```
        $get_leave_id = LeaveApplication::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('statuses_id', 2)
        ->pluck('leave_id');
```

**Getting all leave details from the user**

```
$user_leaves = LeaveApplication::with('leave')
        ->where('statuses_id', '=', 2)
        ->whereIn('leave_id', $get_leave_id)
        ->get();
```

**Model**

```
public function leave()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Leave::class, 'leave_id', 'id');
}
```

**View Page**

{{ $leave->leave->leave_name }} ==> Sick leave

{{ $leave->leave_taken_days }} / {{ $leave->leave->total_leave_days }} ==> 4/12

[Result I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVhke.jpg)

What I want is this

[Result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXuML.jpg)

Please help to build up the query . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the way you collect data as follows:

```
$application = LeaveApplication::with('leave')
               ->where(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'statuses_id' => 2])
               ->first();
```

Then you can count the data as you like:

```
$leave_taken_days = $application->leave->sum('leave_taken_days');
$total_leave_days = $application->leave->sum('total_leave_days');
```

and in the view you can pass the variables directly to the view and call them: `$leave_taken_days` and `$total_leave_days`